# Detect 220Vac signal on Microcontroller

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics, input

I'm developing a module and the control switch may be at long distances.

Considering I have the 127 or 220Vac input, I want to use that for switch signal. I believe is better, instead of making a pull up and send 5V through a long wire where can have a lot of interference.

My idea is to make as the schematic bellow:

[image]

For the optocoupler, I'm considering use [TCMT1109](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83510/tcmt1100.pdf) - CTR > 200%

R1 - to discharge the capacitor when the device gets unplugged.

R2 - to protect against inrush current.

D1 - to ensure C1 can (dis)charge every half cycle and to protect LED D2 against being reverse biased.

Can anybody help me to dimension R1, R2, C1 and D1? Or perhaps indicates a good reference?

Comment: C1 won't reduce the ripple.  It's a capacitive dropper to reduce the current through the LED.  You'd need another capacitor in parallel with the LED to reduce the ripple.

Comment: @SimonB With the circuit as shown in the picture, won't i get pulse in the 'switch output'? Do I need to move the capacitor to parallel with the LED?

Comment: C1 is definitely needed where it is - it limits the current through the circuit.  Without a second capacitor, the LED in the opto isolator will flicker at 60Hz.  If that's OK for you, then don't worry.  If you want the LED to stay on, you need a second capacitor.

Comment: @SimonB Do you have a example of this schematic? or a reference to guide me specific the components?

Comment: I was thinking something like http://www.circuitsgallery.com/2012/07/transformer-less-ac-to-dc-capacitor-power-supply-circuit2.html  Looking at that circuit, I realise that the capacitor is normally **before** the rectifier, not after it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an industry-standard interface isolation module such as...
[image: AC Input, 90-140 VAC, 5 VDC Logic]
http://www.opto22.com/site/pr_details.aspx?cid=4&item=IAC5A

It has the advantage of regulatory approvals to avoid any problems with "home-made" DIY solutions in a commercial or industrial system.

Answer (score 0):

Normally constant current switches are used for long distances with suitable low voltage DC filter. e.g. 4-20mA for sending 0 or 1.  Then disconnect faults can be detected. For sensing line voltage decide on brown out threshold and decide how critical tolerance is, as the opto-tranny has a wide range in hFE.

For current mode, twisted pair immunity is ok with V+ based on conductor losses on both wires.  This is an old std. method for PLC sensors.

Another method would divide AC to 12 or 24 Vdc unfiltered down to send low voltage DC e.g. then drive 10 to 20mA LED opto as a current switch with a suitable RC decay cap on the collector so that switch out is detected below 80V.. Opto-PD's are more accurate than transistors. With opto-diodes gain is often guaranteed to 50% min. so pullup value and threshold can be computed.