# Optocoupler 220V to microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, opto-isolator

I have found optocoupler 220V to microcontroller circuit design like on photo:
[optocoupler 220V to MCU](https://easyeda.com/modules/optocoupler-220v-3-3-5v_60bbb1eda09c45d4a41b309c43a5c1ed)

[image]

I wanted to use it to check 220V presence/absence with MCU.
I need help with understanding how it works.

I assume that R1 is for current limiting, and that D1 provides full-wave rectification, but I don't understand purpose of D2 and C1. C1 is high so its impedance is low to use it for current limiting. I assume that purpose of C1 is to filter full-wave rectified voltage but I don't understand how. Also I don't understand polarity of C1.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Please add a link to the source from where you found the circuit. What is the intended function of the circuit? Just check for presence / absence of 220 V supply? If it was for filtering, the capacitor would have been connected in parallel with the load. "*optocoupler 220V to microcontroller circuit*" seems like an incomplete description of the circuit. What is the desired function of the circuit in plain terms?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below the question to add relevant details to the question.

Comment: Or refer to this one: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/253152/detect-220vac-signal-on-microcontroller

Comment: Without any explanation I would not trust such a schematic. The net is full of erroneous stuff, be careful.

Comment: Just because it's on the internet doesn't make it true.

Comment: try this one instead: https://easyeda.com/modules/Mains-Optocoupler-Module_636e4b1414954220a62c393b90f0924d

Answer (score 1):

D2 - used to suppress negative impulses after  full-wave rectifier D1

It's seems that both LED1 and input-LED in EL817C assumed to work only by pulses after rectification. And, so, C1 - used as DC decoupler. But! In fact, that C1 is in wrong polarity.

And really I dont understand, why this schematic is so complicated. Meny times, for long years I use schem as below.

```
              ______  
~220V >--D1--|  U1  |--> MC pin with internal or ext. pull-up
      >--R1--|______|--GND
```

Where:
D1 - 1N4007 or one of thousand types of rectifier diodes vith reverse voltage about 300V-1000V and forward current from 100mA.
R1 - 0.5W - 1W resistor about 150kOhm
U1 - your EL817C, most famos as PC817C or TLP621

If you whants AC-presents indicator - just add LED in chain D1-Optocoupler-in-R1

Hope, its helpfull.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your simple design. Reverse leakage of D1 can result in exceeding the reverse voltage limit on the U1 opto-LED. R1 would have to be rated for peak mains voltage. Most designs use two or more resistors in series to spread the voltage drop over several devices. Tip: there is a schematic editor button on the editor toolbar. It's easy to use. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: I agree with you. To increase the reliability of the circuit, of course, it should be equipped with a number of additional elements. It all depends on the destination. If you are an engineer in an organization that produces high-load, ultra-reliable telemechanics equipment , you should have developed your own practice of designing such schemes. With suppressors, fuses, self-testing, and so on. But it seems here we are talking about an amateur project? Then, as it seems to me, the main thing here is the cheapness and availability of components.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why C1 is necessary. It is backwards as drawn. It will slowly charge to ~300 VDC so it needs to be a physically large capacitor. As it charges, the diode current becomes smaller and smaller until it will be difficult to sense on the transistor side of the optocoupler. Maybe this is the intent, but I doubt it.

The circuit works much better without C1, assuming that the intent is to detect the zero crossings.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmcMhW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

That circuit makes no sense. it's as-if someone took [this curcuit](https://easyeda.com/modules/Mains-Optocoupler-Module_636e4b1414954220a62c393b90f0924d/editor#id=!636e4b1414954220a62c393b90f0924d):

[image]

Changed D2 and rotated C1

Even this curcuit doen't make a lot of sense, the Zener doide is going to do precisely nothing useful, and the capacitor cpould be substituted for a smaller capacitor at the output for much the same result. But at-least this one does something useful.